# Laravel 5 Seeder Class Does Not Exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I have a fresh Laravel installation. I have moved over code from a github repository that is a Laravel project, same version (5.3).

Everything works fine, except for some reason the database seeds wont' run.

For example, I can migrate from the github loaded migrations in the new Laravel installation, just as I would on the server that pushed the migrations to github in the first place.

But I can't do `php artisan db:seed`, which means my beautiful little database is empty! >:(

I get: **ReflectionException Class does not exist**

What I have tried:

1. `php artisan optimize`
2. `php artisan clear:cache`
3. `composer clearcache`
4. `composer dump-autoload`

None of which have solved my problem. Everything in `DatabaseSeeder` is spelled correctly and the classes -do- exist, they work fine on my other server, and again, this fresh install now has all the same files as my origin server, thanks to Github.

DatabaseSeeder.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Edit - Stack Trace:

```
2017-06-14 19:11:00] local.ERROR: ReflectionException: Class UserTablesSeeder does not exist in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:749
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(749): ReflectionClass->__construct('UserTablesSeede...')
#1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(644): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('UserTablesSeede...', Array)
#2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('UserTablesSeede...', Array)
#3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('UserTablesSeede...')
#4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php(43): Illuminate\Database\Seeder->resolve('UserTablesSeede...')
#5 /var/www/laravel/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php(14): Illuminate\Database\Seeder->call('UserTablesSeede...')
#6 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php(63): DatabaseSeeder->run()
#7 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2292): Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand->Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeedCommand.php(64): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguarded(Object(Closure))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand->fire()
#10 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(508): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#12 /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(261): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(817): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(185): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/laravel/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 {main}
```

Comment: Have you made a database seeder?

Comment: If so, please provide that code

Comment: @Derek code added

Comment: My apologies, I mean the `UserTableSeeder` code

Comment: @Derek It's quite long, don't thing I can include the whole thing. If it helps though, I did remove it from the `run()` call in favor of another seed and got the same error with that class. So it's not particular to that code. It seems to be across any seeder I make, but I don't want to start introducing new seeders or deleting some because it's supposed to mirror the git repo from which they were pulled.

Comment: Check the laravel.log in `storage/logs` and find out where the error actually occurs.

Comment: @Robert edited question with the laravel log output

Comment: `UserTablesSeeder` vs `UserTableSeeder`, Tables vs Table

Comment: @Robert That's so weird, I don't have anything called `UserTablesSeeder` so why does it pick that up? In `DatabaseSeeder` it says `$this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);`

Comment: @Robert The actual class itself is declared with `class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{`

Comment: Try to run the `composer install` command again and watch out for any kind of error.

Comment: @brunohdaniel I did that and go no error... my middleware also does not work.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper have you solve the issue?

Answer (score 20):

try running

```
composer dump-autoload
```

especially if you have recently edited the name of your seeder file

Comment: thank you! this is better than any other methods. this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got around the problem by picking out an individual class:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder
```

As oppose to `db:seed` without any arguments, however I would still like to know why I have to do this.

Again, I don't have `UserTablesSeeder`anywhere in my code so not sure why the log shows this is the seed attempt when I never declare that.

It's always `UserTableSeeder` without the `s` in `Table`.

**Edit:** And now my custom middleware doesn't work... seems to be an issue with the fresh install not liking some of the new code from github... if anyone can provide a better answer I will gladly accept.

Comment: Still could be a composer issue. Remove the vendor dir completely and the composer.lock file. After that run composer again for a fresh install. If you can, check the vendor/composer dir and grep for UserTables somewhere in the autoload files.

Comment: @Robert Okay will try this and get back to you. I will just install and pull from github all over and see if I can spot anything going wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm having this problem now. Know the answer?

Comment: Weird. When I ran `php artisan db:seed --env=testing` I got `Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist`, so then I ran `php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder` but got `Seeder already exists!`. Bizarre. I deleted the file and then re-ran the maker, and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

For **Laravel 6.0**, changing

```
$this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
```

to

```
$this->call('UserTableSeeder');
```

Did the trick for me.

Comment: Where to change this

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the seed file and re-make it, all works fine.